# Mongoose delete array element in document

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I am stuck in this point,I have a Team model which is given below.

```
var teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type : String
},
members :[
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
    }
],
leads:[
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
    }
],
admin_rights :[
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
    }
],
view_rights :[
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
    }
]
});
```

I make a reference of `User Schema`  in this model.
I want to delete the one element in `leads` array. I tried many times but it shows following..

```
{
"n": 1,
"nModified": 0,
"opTime": {
    "ts": "6797745245908893697",
    "t": 4
},
"electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000004",
"ok": 1,
"operationTime": "6797745245908893697",
"$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": "6797745245908893697",
    "signature": {
        "hash": "Sdl1QzsqCcO7SKS95+N1Gx7rkJY=",
        "keyId": "6762348659485966337"
    }
}
}
```

this is code to delete the array element but its not working.

```
router.get('/deletelead', (req, res) => {
var _id = req.query.team_id;
var id_to_delete = req.query.id;


Team.update({ _id: _id }, { "$pull": { "leads": { id_to_delete }  } }, { safe: true }, function(err, obj) {
    if(!err){
        res.json(obj)
    }
    else
    res.json(err)
});
});
```

I checked the other same questions on stackoverflow but I can not resolve my issue.

What would be the proper request to achieve that?

Comment: Did you try to convert `id_to_delete` into `ObjectId`?

Comment: no how can i do this?

Comment: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id_to_delete)

Comment: i check it but no change. respose is same

Comment: @HammadAli : Not sure how it's `n:1` but you can try this `Team.update({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) }, { "$pull": { "leads": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id_to_delete) } }`, You don't have to use safe option as it's defaults to true.

Comment: Thank you @whoami its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/deletelead', (req, res) => {
    var _id = req.query.team_id;
    var id_to_delete = req.query.id;

    Team.update({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) }, { "$pull": { "leads": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id_to_delete) } }, function (err, obj) {
        if (!err) {
            res.json(obj)
        }
        else
            res.json(err)
    });
});
```

There are couple of changes :

1. You need to convert all values into type `ObjectId()` if those fields are of type `ObjectId()` in database.
2. Also in `$pull` value can be directly assigned to `leads` but not like an object.
3. You don't need to specify `safe :true` as all mongoose schemas defaults to that option. **Ref :** [mongoose-safe-option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/guide.html#safe)